# Symfony2 authenticated users are redirected to login page on Access Denied exception

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, redirect

When the user is not authenticated, on Access Denied it is redirected to login page, this is fine.

But when it is authenticated, it should stay on Access Denied page and display the error message, but it is redirected to login page, then that page throws Access Denied exception (because only not authenticated users can access the login page) and that creates an infinite redirect loop.

```
providers:
    app_user:
        entity:
            class: AppUserBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            #check_path: route_id
            login_path: app_user_login
        provider: app_user
        #logout:
        #    path:   route_id
        #    target: route_id
        anonymous: ~
```

I have commented `# check_path:` because I use custom register/login pages and my login form is submitted to `login_path:`. That worked well until I moved my provider to `entity`. Before that I had a custom provider that loaded users from Cassandra database.

I found the problem: My site is using remember_me authentications, but in Symfony there is [this line](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/58efb98c6fa6d3d4f63cbaf31a6ca86e23782b2f/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php#L120) that is executed on AccessDenied exception. When I changed `->isFullFledged($token)` to `->isRememberMe($token)` everything works fine. Do you think this is [a Symfony bug](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15370)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user returns to your site, they are authenticated automatically based on the information stored in the remember me cookie. This allows the user to access protected resources **as if the user had actually authenticated** upon visiting the site. ([source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html#forcing-the-user-to-re-authenticate-before-accessing-certain-resources))

So the user is not trusted until it is authenticated fully. That's why it is redirected to login page when an AccessDenied exception occurs.

On login controller action I have set annotation

```
@Security("not is_authenticated()")
```

that way I tried to allow only anonymous users to that page, with fully authenticated users that worked well, but when I switched my site to use only remember_me, here is what happens

```
if @Security(...) is False {
    if IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY {
        displayAccessDeniedPage()
    } else {
        redirectToLoginPage() 
    } 
}
```

The solution is to:

- Remove `@Security(..)` from login controller action (allow everyone to access it)
- In controller action, check programatically

  ```
  if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
      throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('You are already logged in');
  }
  ```
- When the user is logged in programatically, set both full and remember_me tokens (not only remember_me)

---

Same problem is with register action

- I must remove `@Security("not is_authenticated()")`
- Check programatically

  ```
  if ($this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('Only anonymous users can access this page');
  }
  ```

Note the `createNotFoundException()`, I can't use  `createAccessDeniedException()` because the remember_me users will be redirected to login page when they will try to access the register page (weird).